# How to fix Missing slash tag while adding route paramters in laravel

Tags: laravel, routes, query-string

I am trying to print multiple slideshows which are contatinaned inside  tags which are defined like this
 `<a href="{{url('/klubet/') .$dt->id}}">` Everything is inside this foreach loop `@foreach( $data as $dt)`The route of the page i am using is `/klubet` and after clicking the link i want it to be /klubet/id but it appears to be /klubetid without the /

Comment: `{{ url('/klubet/'.$dt->id) }}`.

Comment: thank it worked but it looks the same where is the difference?

Comment: `url()` generates a url without an ending slash. So instead of concatenating `$dt->id` to the result of  `url('/klubet/')` , you concatenate it to `'/klubet/'`

Comment: oh ok i get it thank you